# Jqplot: Why are 0 bars rendering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I am having an issue with jqplot where stacked bars are sometimes displaying a bar for 0. I don't want a bar for 0. All of the numbers associated with each bar add up to the max. Here is what I am seeing.

[Stacked bars with 0 labels removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Z9X.jpg)

The problem is with MS/AL (27 stops). There is a blue bar, but that bar represents 0. This doesn't always happen though. There is actually a third color that could show in the bar, but none of this example shows it.

Here is an example with point labels showing the 0 (instead of hideZeros:true) just to prove that 0 is causing a bar to render.

[Stacked bars with labels for 0s](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DtC5.jpg)

Here is my javascript:

```
$.jqplot(div_id, customer_amount, {
                            title:{
                                text: v.truck_label+' ('+v.count+' stops)',
                                textAlign: 'left'
                            },
                            animate: true,
                            stackSeries: true,
                            axesDefaults:{
                                showTicks: false,
                                tickOptions:{
                                    show: false,
                                    showTicks: false,
                                    showGridline: false
                                },
                                rendererOptions: {
                                    baselineWidth: 1.5,
                                    drawBaseline: false
                                }
                            },
                            seriesDefaults:{
                                renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                                rendererOptions: {
                                    barDirection: 'horizontal',
                                    highlightMouseOver: false,
                                    //shadow: false
                                    shadowAngle: 35,
                                    shadowAlpha: 0.1,
                                    shadowDepth: 4
                                },
                                pointLabels: {
                                    show: true,
                                    formatString: '%d',
                                    hideZeros:true
                                }
                            },
                            axes: {
                                yaxis: {
                                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                                    showTicks: false,
                                    ticks: [''],
                                    tickOptions:{
                                        show: false,
                                        showGridline: false
                                    }
                                },
                                xaxis: {
                                    max: max,
                                    showTicks: false,
                                    tickOptions:{
                                        show: false,
                                        showGridline: false
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            grid: {
                                drawGridLines: false,
                                drawBorder: false,
                                shadow: false,
                                borderColor: 'transparent',
                                background: 'transparent'
                            },
                            seriesColors: series_colors

});
```

Does anybody know what is happening? Any suggestions?

Comment: Replace pointLabels: {
                                    show: true,
                                    formatString: '%d',
                                    hideZeros:true
                                }
with 
pointLabels: {
                show: true,
                hideZeros: true
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the working fiddle...

```
var options = {
        title: 'Title ',
        stackSeries: true,
        seriesColors: ["#eb4b3d", "#ffc800", "#009149"],
        seriesDefaults: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
            pointLabels: {
                show: true,
                hideZeros: true
            },
            rendererOptions: {
                barWidth: 25,
                varyBarColor: true,
            },
        },
        axes: {
            xaxis: {
                // renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                //  
                renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                ticks: ticks,
            },
            yaxis: {
                //autoscale: true,
                //label: 'Application Count',
                min: 0,
                tickInterval: 5,
                max: 50
            }
        },
        axesDefaults: {
            tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,
            tickOptions: {
                angle: -30,
                fontSize: '10pt'
            }
        }
    };
```

http://jsfiddle.net/arzv5j6o/3/

Comment: Applying min: 0 to the axis solved it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! Can you please vote up too?

Comment: Wish I could. Apparently I don't have enough reputation to upvote.